# SCALA: Fold method with conditions

Tags: scala, functional-programming, foldleft

I am still learning the basics of Scala, therefore I am asking for your understanding. Is it any possible way to use fold method to print only names beginning with "A"

```
Object Scala {
  val names: List[String] = List("Adam", "Mick", "Ann");
  def main(args: Array[String]) {
  println(names.foldLeft("my list of items starting with A: ")(_+_));  
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Well you can `filter` before the fold. Or do the predicate inside the fold, like `case (acc, elem) => if (elem.startsWith("A")) acc + elem else acc }`

Comment: Building on what @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez said, you can do something like `names.filter(_.startsWith("A")).mkString(", ")` instead of a fold

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the signature of `foldLeft`

```
def foldLeft[B](z: B)(op: (B, A) => B): B
```

where

- `z` is the initial value
- `op` is a function taking two arguments, namely accumulated result so far `B`, and the next element to be processed `A`
- returns the accumulated result `B`

Now consider this concrete implementation

```
val names: List[String] = List("Adam", "Mick", "Ann")
val predicate: String => Boolean = str => str.startsWith("A")

names.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) { (accumulated: List[String], next: String) =>
  if (predicate(next)) accumulated.prepended(next) else accumulated
}
```

here

```
z = List.empty[String]
op = (accumulated: List[String], next: String) => if (predicate(next)) accumulated.prepended(next) else accumulated
```

Usually we would write this inlined and rely on type inference so we do not have two write out full types all the time, so it becomes

```
names.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) { (acc, next) =>
  if (next.startsWith("A")) next :: acc else acc
}
// val res1: List[String] = List(Ann, Adam)
```

On of the key ideas when working with `List` is to always prepend an element instead of append

```
names.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) { (accumulated: List[String], next: String) =>
  if (predicate(next)) accumulated.appended(next) else accumulated
}
```

because prepending is much more efficient. However note how this makes the accumulated result in reverse order, so

```
List(Ann, Adam)
```

instead of perhaps required

```
List(Adam, Ann)
```

so often-times we perform one last traversal by calling `reverse` like so

```
names.foldLeft(List.empty[String]) { (acc, next) =>
  if (next.startsWith("A")) next :: acc else acc
}.reverse
// val res1: List[String] = List(Adam, Ann)
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer from @Mario Galic is a good one and should be accepted. (It's the polite thing to do).

Here's a slightly different way to filter for *starts-with-A* strings.

```
val names: List[String] = List("Adam", "Mick", "Ann")

println(names.foldLeft("my list of items starting with A: "){
  case (acc, s"A$nme") => acc + s"A$nme "
  case (acc, _ ) => acc
})

//output: "my list of items starting with A: Adam Ann"
```